# position font-awesome icons above navbar links

Tags: icons, navbar, font-awesome

I've got a stacked bootstrap navbar using font-awesome icons.  I'd like to position the icons above each navbar link instead of to the left.  I found a wordpress theme that does what I'm trying to accomplish and included a link here:

[wordpress theme with icons in navbar](http://themes.semicolonweb.com/wp/coworker/header-6/)

This is the code for what I currently have, pretty straight forward bootstrap stacked nav.

```
<section class="row-fluid">
    <nav class="span2">
        <ul class="side-nav nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
          <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-large icon-home"></i> Dashboard</a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-large icon-key"></i> Licenses</a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-large icon-download-alt"></i> Downloads</a></li> 
          <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-large icon-question-sign"></i> Get help</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 2):

This depends on whether you want the pills left stacked or put side-by-side. You can see both of these options in this [working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qpuU3/1/).

**Stacked HTML:**

```
<section class="row-fluid">
    <nav class="span2">
        <ul class="side-nav nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
            <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-large icon-home"></i><br> <div class="wrd">Dashboard</div></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-large icon-key"></i><br> <div class="wrd">Licenses</div></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-large icon-download-alt"></i><br> <div class="wrd">Downloads</div></a></li> 
          <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-large icon-question-sign"></i><br> <div class="wrd">Get help</div></a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</section>
```

**Side-by-side:**

```
<section class="row-fluid">
    <nav class="span2">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills">
            <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-large icon-home"></i><br> <div class="wrd">Dashboard</div></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-large icon-key"></i><br> <div class="wrd">Licenses</div></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-large icon-download-alt"></i><br> <div class="wrd">Downloads</div></a></li> 
          <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-large icon-question-sign"></i><br> <div class="wrd">Get help</div></a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</section>
```

Essentially, you just have to override one or two of the default **CSS rules**:

```
li {
    text-align: center;
}
.icon-large {
    font-size: 14pt;
}
.wrd {
    padding-top: 5px !important;
}
```